# Novel about rebirth/reincarnation

Tags: story-identification

I am searching for a novel about an old, successful orphan lady who died peacefully. She is reborn as a little girl in a *parallel underdeveloped (semi-) magic world* and then abandoned. She disguises herself as a little boy and earns money by fishing in a creek. With the help of her neighbours she builds a small hut and adopts her younger sister.

She discovers she has superpowers. There are those who travel around the world trying to find children like her. They opened an academy.

Eventually she is adopted by the sister of(?) the queen.

I remember a scene where they can make clouds to create rain and they can raid on clouds. I think they can breathe underwater as well.

Before the protagonist came along, potatoes were used as fodder for animals. She introduces this world to French fries, pizza and ice cream.

The novel was written in English and read around last two years (2018/19).

Comment: *"can from clouds to raid on it."* - I didn't understand this sentence.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, **what superpowers did she have? What was her name? What was the name of the academy? When did you read it? What did it have on the cover? Was it written in English or another language?**

Comment: @Valorum I think there were a couple of typos and it was meant to say "can form clouds to rain on it", but it would be nice if OP could clarify.

Comment: @F1Krazy - There were more than a couple of typos when I started :-) But that sounds like it makes sense. Rain powers?

Comment: Ahh. It sounds like she's been reborn from our world into another fantasy world. Was this some sort of [Isekai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isekai) light novel?

Comment: this should be a Chinese translation in English.. magic realism kinda..no game or novel birth stuff..parallel underdevelop (semi )magic  world..

Comment: she is not only one reborn in the world .she later finds out the head of the orphanage was also reborn with power (the lady  can see others powers )

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to this site.  Did you mean to say, "ride on clouds", rather than "raid on clouds"?